# Specify start and the end of range query by using the index

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Suppose that I have 2 columns, where 1st column is row data, and 2nd column is the conjunction of 16 cells of the 1st row.

```
ASD  =JOINTEXT(" ",FALSE, A1:A16)
BBC
ASD
FDG
WRE
SDS
ASF
```

Now, for my second cell in 2nd column, I want to do the same thing but with range of A17 to A32, and so on. So how to utilize the index of the cell of the second column to change the range that I am looking for?

Comment: what is JOINTEXT?  did you mean TEXTJOIN?

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX and some math to do the iterations:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",FALSE,INDEX(A:A,(ROW(1:1)-1)*16+1):INDEX(A:A,ROW(1:1)*16))
```

Comment: and what would be the way to put the 1st column's row number in between? Like: 0 ASD 1 BBC 2 ASD and so on?

Comment: New questions, get new posts